# Prompt not working

Tags: javascript, window, prompt

I have a problem in my code somewhere in the var myAge (first line). I have loaded the browser up but cannot get the prompt window to open. Any thoughts on what's wrong with the code?

```
 <script>
var myAge = parseInt( prompt("enter your age", 30), 10 );

if (myAge >= 0 && myAge <= 10) {
    document.write("myAge is between 0 and 10 <br/>");
}

if ( !(myAge >= 0 && myAge <= 10) {
    document.write("myAge is NOT between 0 and 10 <br/>");  
}

if (myAge >= 80 || myAge <= 10) {
    document.write("myAge is 80 or above OR 10 or below.<br/>");    
}

if ( (myAge >= 30 && myAge <= 39) || (myAge >= 80 && myAge <= 89) ) {
    document.write("myAge is between 30 and 39 and 39 or myAge is " + "between 80 and 88"); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: any errors in the console? what browser have you tried? is the page laoded using `http[s]://` or `file:///`

Comment: why don't you try alert()

Comment: if prompt doesn't work, alert wont either

Comment: @JaromandaX, I have dreamweaver running and it won't open the prompt either. I've tried Chrome, and IE. Page is loaded with file:///

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed a paranthesis in the second-if block..... also close the script tag.

```js
var myAge = parseInt( prompt("enter your age", 30), 10 );

if (myAge >= 0 && myAge <= 10) {
    document.write("myAge is between 0 and 10 <br/>");
}

if ( !(myAge >= 0 && myAge <= 10)) {
    document.write("myAge is NOT between 0 and 10 <br/>");  
}

if (myAge >= 80 || myAge <= 10) {
    document.write("myAge is 80 or above OR 10 or below.<br/>");    
}

if ( (myAge >= 30 && myAge <= 39) || (myAge >= 80 && myAge <= 89) ) {
    document.write("myAge is between 30 and 39 and 39 or myAge is " + "between 80 and 88"); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I see it. Such a simple solution.